# scanf from console and fscanf from file

Tags: printf, scanf

I got some problems about scanf from console,
I wrote some codes about it and found that it could not read all the input and automatically close after typing first character.

```
int readLetterGridFromConsole(char letterGrid[MAX_GRID][MAX_GRID]) {
    int row, col;
    int gridSize;

    printf("Enter the size of the letter grid:\n");
    scanf("%d", &gridSize);

     if(gridSize < 2 || gridSize > MAX_GRID) {
        printf("DEBUG: gridSize is %d but not between 2 and %d\n", gridSize, MAX_GRID);
        printf("Program terminates.\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {

    printf("Enter the letter grid:\n");


    for(row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
        for(col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {

        scanf(" %c", &letterGrid[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return gridSize;
    }
}
```

I would like to store these input in the 2D array ( letterGrid )
how could I solve this problem? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

But it works for me.

I define a 2-D array `char x[MAX_GRID][MAX_GRID];` then pass it to function, then scan input then store them in the x matrix.

---

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_GRID 2

int readLetterGridFromConsole(char letterGrid[MAX_GRID][MAX_GRID]) {
    int row, col;
    int gridSize;

    printf("Enter the size of the letter grid:\n");
    scanf("%d", &gridSize);

     if(gridSize < 2 || gridSize > MAX_GRID) {
        printf("DEBUG: gridSize is %d but not between 2 and %d\n", gridSize, MAX_GRID);
        printf("Program terminates.\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {

    printf("Enter the letter grid:\n");


    for(row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
        for(col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {
            scanf(" %c", &letterGrid[row][col]);
        }
    }

    //return gridSize;
    }



/*
    printf("Lettr grid\n\n");

    for(row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {
        for(col = 0; col < gridSize; col++) {
            printf("%c", letterGrid[row][col]);
        }
    }
*/    


} 


int main()
{  
    char x[MAX_GRID][MAX_GRID];//={{1,2},{3,4}};
    readLetterGridFromConsole(x);

    printf("after function\n\n\n");
     for(int row = 0; row < MAX_GRID; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < MAX_GRID; col++) {
            printf("%c", x[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

***Compile and Run***

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors code.c -o code`

**Output**

> Enter the size of the letter grid:
>   2
>
> Enter the letter grid:
>   a
>   b
>   c
>   d
>
> after function
>
> abcd

---

Consider as array in c pass by reference it can hold values even outside of function `readLetterGridFromConsole(x);`